# ExpandableListView won't inflate/initialise in fragment code

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I keep getting a null pointer exception when ever I try to run a fragment that must use an expandable list view item. I'm guessing it has something to do with the fragment because the similar code runs on an activity.

Here is the error (Logcat) message:

```
11-02 14:11:27.136 12947-12947/com.example.vhuhwavho.ctistudentportal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.vhuhwavho.ctistudentportal, PID: 12947
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.vhuhwavho.ctistudentportal.ForYouFragment.onCreateView(ForYouFragment.java:117)
    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1453)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the fragment code:

```
package com.example.vhuhwavho.ctistudentportal;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

/**
 * Created by Vhuhwavho on 2017/10/31.
*/

public class ForYouFragment extends Fragment {

// To keep track of the counter, we need to add a global variable to the project,
// along with a key for saving and restoring.
static final String KEY_STUDENT_NUMBER = "studentNumber";
String studentNumber = "";

private static final int CODE_GET_REQUEST = 1024;
private static final int CODE_POST_REQUEST = 1025;

private Button mSubmit;
private Context mContext;

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private View view;

private List < String > listHeadings;
private List < String > image_urls;
private List < Bitmap > images;
private List < String > messages;

private LinkedHashMap   < String, GroupInfo > gMessages = new LinkedHashMap < String, GroupInfo > ();
private ArrayList       < GroupInfo >         list = new ArrayList     < GroupInfo > ();

private ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
private ExpandableListView simpleExpandableListView;

//Connectivity manage instance
private ConnectivityManager mConnMgr;

// Image view reference
private ImageView imageView;

int imageCounter = 0, imageCounterSize = 0;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
     view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.for_you_fragment, container, false);

    String extraStr;

    try {
        extraStr = getArguments().getString("studentNumber");
        Log.e("try studentNumber", "tried student number");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        studentNumber = "PT2014-1282";
        Log.e("catch studentNumber", "catched student number");
    }


    requestForYou();

    //get reference of the ExpandableListView
    simpleExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.simpleExpandableListView);

    if ( simpleExpandableListView == null )
        Log.d("Null or Not", "simpleExpandableList == null");

    // create the adapter by passing your ArrayList data
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter (this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), list);

    // attach the adapter to the expandable list view
    simpleExpandableListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    //expand all the Groups
    expandAll();

    // setOnChildClickListener listener for child row click
    simpleExpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            //get the group header
            GroupInfo headerInfo = list.get(groupPosition);
            //get the child info
            ChildInfo detailInfo =  headerInfo.getHeadingList().get(childPosition);
            //display it or do something with it
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " Clicked on :: " + headerInfo.getHeading()
                    + "/" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    // setOnGroupClickListener listener for group heading click
    simpleExpandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {

            //get the group header
            GroupInfo headerInfo = list.get(groupPosition);

            //display it or do something with it

            return false;
        }
    });


    listHeadings = new ArrayList<>();
    messages     = new ArrayList<>();
    image_urls   = new ArrayList<>();

    return view;

} // end of onCreateView method


// To receive notifications of application state change, 2 methods are needed
// the onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() methods
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString(KEY_STUDENT_NUMBER, studentNumber);

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated (savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        studentNumber = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_STUDENT_NUMBER);
    }

}

// save the data before the activity closes
@Override
public void onPause () {

    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences settings = this.getActivity().getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(KEY_STUDENT_NUMBER, studentNumber);
    editor.commit();
}

//method to expand all groups
private void expandAll() {
    int count = listAdapter.getGroupCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        simpleExpandableListView.expandGroup(i);
    }
}

//method to collapse all groups
private void collapseAll() {
    int count = listAdapter.getGroupCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        simpleExpandableListView.collapseGroup(i);
    }
}

private void requestForYou () {

    PerformNetworkRequest request = new PerformNetworkRequest(API.URL_REQUEST_FOR_YOU, CODE_GET_REQUEST);
    request.execute();

}

private void refreshForYou( JSONArray forYou)  throws JSONException {

    for ( int i = 0; i < forYou.length(); i++ ) {

        JSONObject whats_happening = forYou.getJSONObject(i);

        String heading      = whats_happening.getString( "heading" );
        String image_url    = whats_happening.getString( "url" );
        String message      = whats_happening.getString( "message" );

        listHeadings.add    ( heading ) ;
        messages.add         ( message );
        image_urls.add      ( image_url );

        Log.d("ForYouFragment", "refreshForYou");

    }

    imageCounterSize = listHeadings.size();

    if ( mConnMgr != null ) {

        // Get active network info
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = mConnMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        // If any active network is available and internet connection is available
        if ( networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected() ) {

            for ( String url : image_urls ) {
                // Start a new Image Download Async Task
                new DownloadImageTask().execute( url );
            }

        } else {
            // If network is off or internet is not available, inform the user
            Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Network not Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    Log.d("ForYouFragment", "Finished refreshForYou");

    for ( int loadData = 0; loadData < imageCounterSize; loadData++ ) {

        addMessage ( listHeadings.get( loadData ) , messages.get( loadData ) , images.get( loadData ));

    }

}

//here we maintain our products in various departments
private int addMessage ( String heading, String message, Bitmap image ){

    int groupPosition = 0;

    //check the hash map if the group already exists
    GroupInfo headerInfo = gMessages.get(heading);

    //add the group if doesn't exists
    if( headerInfo == null ) {

        headerInfo = new GroupInfo();
        headerInfo.setHeading(heading);

        gMessages.put(heading, headerInfo);
        list.add(headerInfo);

    }

    //get the children for the group
    ArrayList<ChildInfo> productList = headerInfo.getHeadingList();

    //size of the children list
    int listSize = productList.size();

    //add to the counter
    listSize++;

    //create a new child and add that to the group
    ChildInfo detailInfo = new ChildInfo();
    detailInfo.setSequence ( String.valueOf( listSize ) );
    detailInfo.setMessage ( message );
    productList.add ( detailInfo );
    headerInfo.setHeadingList ( productList );

    //find the group position inside the list
    groupPosition = list.indexOf(headerInfo);

    return groupPosition;

}

public class PerformNetworkRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    String url;
    HashMap < String, String > params; // Store the names of the subjects enrolled
    int requestCode;

    PerformNetworkRequest ( String URL, int code ) {

        url = URL;
        requestCode = code;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute( String s ) {

        Log.d("fetchWhatsHappening", "onPostExecute Register Response: " + s.toString());

        super.onPostExecute( s );

        try {

            JSONObject root_object = new JSONObject( s );
            JSONArray array = root_object.getJSONArray("for_you");
            Log.d("GET URL", "Checking URL... " + API.URL_REQUEST_FOR_YOU );

            if (!root_object.getBoolean("error")) {
                Toast.makeText( getActivity(), root_object.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                refreshForYou ( array );
            } else {



            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

        if (requestCode == CODE_POST_REQUEST)
            return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(url, params);


        if (requestCode == CODE_GET_REQUEST)
            return requestHandler.sendGetRequest(url);

        return null;

    } // end of  doInBackground method

} // end of PerformNetworkRequest class

/*--------------------------- Setting ListView and Downloading Images ------------------------*/

public class GroupInfo {

    private String heading;
    private Bitmap image;
    private ArrayList < ChildInfo > list = new ArrayList < ChildInfo >();

    public String getHeading() {

        return heading;

    }

    public void setHeading ( String heading ) {

        this.heading = heading;

    }

    public void setImage (Bitmap image) {

        this.image = image;

    }

    public Bitmap getImage () {

        return image;

    }

    public ArrayList < ChildInfo > getHeadingList() {

        return list;

    }

    public void setHeadingList(ArrayList<ChildInfo> headingList) {

        this.list = headingList;

    }

}

public class ChildInfo {

    private String sequence = "";
    private String message = "";

    public String getSequence() {

        return sequence;

    }

    public void setSequence(String sequence) {

        this.sequence = sequence;

    }


    public String getMessage() {

        return message;

    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {

        this.message = message;

    }

}


public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<GroupInfo> forYou;

    public ExpandableListAdapter (Context applicationContext, ArrayList<GroupInfo> forYou ) {

        this.context = context;
        this.forYou = forYou;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater.from( applicationContext ) );

    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild( int groupPosition, int childPosition ) {

        ArrayList < ChildInfo > headingList = forYou.get(groupPosition).getHeadingList();

        return headingList.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId( int groupPosition, int childPosition ) {

        return childPosition;

    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                             View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.for_you_list_item, null);

        ChildInfo detailInfo = (ChildInfo) getChild( groupPosition, childPosition );

        TextView childItem = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.forYouMessage );
        childItem.setText( detailInfo.getMessage().trim() );

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount ( int groupPosition ) {

        ArrayList < ChildInfo > headingList = forYou.get( groupPosition ).getHeadingList();

        return headingList.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {

        return forYou.get(groupPosition);

    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {

        return forYou.size();

    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {

        return groupPosition;

    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view,
                             ViewGroup parent) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.for_you_heading_list_view, null);

        GroupInfo headerInfo = (GroupInfo) getGroup(groupPosition);

        TextView heading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.forYouHeading);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.forYouIcon);

        heading.setText(headerInfo.getHeading().trim());
        image.setImageBitmap(headerInfo.getImage());

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

} // end of ExpandableListAdapter


private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask < String, Void, Bitmap >  {


    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return downloadImage ( urls[0] );
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (Bitmap bitmap) {

        if ( imageCounter < imageCounterSize ) {

            if (bitmap == null) {

                Drawable vectorDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.no_image, null);
                Bitmap no_image = ((BitmapDrawable) vectorDrawable).getBitmap();

                images.add(no_image);

            }
            else if (bitmap != null) { // Add the newly downloaded image to the list

                images.add( bitmap );

            }

            imageCounter++;
        }


    } // end of onPostExecute

}


public Bitmap downloadImage (String path) {
    final String TAG = "Download Task";

    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    InputStream inStream;

    try {

        // Create a URL Connection object and set its parameters
        URL url = new URL(path);

        HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Set connection time out of 5 seconds
        urlConn.setConnectTimeout(5000);

        // Set connection time out of 2.5 seconds
        urlConn.setReadTimeout(2500);

        // Set HTTP request method
        urlConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConn.setDoInput(true);


        // Perform network request
        inStream = urlConn.getInputStream();


        // Convert the input stream to Bitmap object
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream);


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "URL error : " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Download Failed : " + e.getMessage());}

    return bitmap;
}

}
```

Here's the for_you_fragment.xml file with the ExpandableListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/simpleExpandableListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="#f00"
        android:childDivider="#0f0"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the list_item.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/forYouMessage"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the list_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/forYouIcon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/forYouHeading"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/forYouIcon"
        android:text="..."
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `view.findViewById()` instead of `this.getActivity().findViewById()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are passing wrong context here:

```
//get reference of the ExpandableListView
simpleExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.simpleExpandableListView);
```

You have to pass the view which you are inflating as follow:

```
simpleExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.simpleExpandableListView);
```

Comment: Thank You Kind Sir

Comment: @King if answer will help you to then don't forgot to tick as right answer.. happy coding..!!

Comment: @Munir I just read your solution so I just added little detail to it so that it may help original poster conceptually